# Space Between col-md fix?(bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, col

When I use a `col-md` class it sometimes shows a space between the movies. We don't want it like that.

If you know any better code to use for this kind of layout please tell us!

http://prntscr.com/6bwcpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in CSS file
     .movie{
         height:200px;
         width: 200px; 
         float: left; 
      }

in html page
    <div class="row">
            <div class="movie" >
                   movie1
              </div >
               <div class="movie" > 
                  movie2 >
               </div>
      ..............
    </div>

Comment: We use a MySQL database to loop through every movie. So I don't know.